# CSS bootstrap nav bar right side items fail to align correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working with bootstrap, 
and I have this navbar:

```
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Lead Manager</a>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/register" className="navbar-link">Register</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/login" className="navbar-link">Login</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

I am using boostrap cdn 4.4.1:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.4.1/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

And yet, I keep getting this:
[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `ml-auto` to the end of the class list for the `<ul>` containing 'Register' and 'Login'

Comment: That got the items to the right.  How do I fix the spacing between them?  Thanks!

Comment: Your alignment worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `<div class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></div>` right after `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">`. Also change the class name `navbar-link` as `nav-link` of your `<Link/>` components.

See the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rnm617jz/1/

Note: I have changed the `className` attr as `class`, since I don't have React in the demo and wanted to test it without it.

Comment: THe bigger issue was the alignment in which Zack answered.  You got the css navbar-link to nav-link.  I appreciate that.  I want to set both to correct answers but I can't.  Thanks still +1

Answer (score 0):

just add `ml-auto` class next to `navbar-nav`, will do the trick.

```
<ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
```

to fix your navbar links change `navbar-link` class to `nav-link`

```
<Link to="/" className="nav-link">sample</Link>
```